# Confusion on Probability Problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Suppose there are 25 indistinguishable balls which can go
into 7 urns in such a way that all configurations of balls are equally likely. For example,
(3, 0, 7, 9, 2, 1, 3) and (0, 18, 1, 1, 0, 0, 5) are equally likely, where the the ith number is the
number of balls in urn i. Given that all 7 urns have at least one ball, what is the
probability that one of the urns has at least 15 balls? Hint: is it possible that more than
one urn has at least 15 balls at a time?

My thinking: Because each urn must have one ball, there are ${{25-1} \choose {7-1}} = {24 \choose 6}$ total solutions.

The probability that one has exactly 15 is

$$\frac{{7 \choose 1} \times {25 \choose 15} \times {6 \choose 6} \times {9 \choose 5}}{{24 \choose 6}}$$

I planned to do that for 16, 17, and 18, then add them. However, the numerator is significantly larger than the denominator, so this is clearly not the way to go.

Comment: Can you explain to me how you arrived at your numerator and denominator?

Comment: We have been given the formula (n-1)C(r-1) for total solutions when each element has at least 1 solution in it (phrasing might be poor). Because each urn must have at least one ball, the equation would be: x1 + x2 + x3 + ... + x7 = 25. This led me to 24C6. For the numerator, there are 25 balls, in which (in my first calculation) exactly 15 will be in one and the 6 will be distributed elsewhere. There are 7 options for which we need to choose 15 from 25. For the other 10, each bucket must have one so we need to use the formula described early. This got me to (10-1)C(6-1) = 9C5.

Comment: There are seven options of which urn can get fifteen balls. But since the balls are indistinguishable, we don't get $25C15$ ways to choose $15$ balls to put into that urn. Any fifteen balls are indistinguishable from any other fifteen balls

Comment: Are you familiar with "stars and bars"?

Comment: Partially. I see where you are going with the fact that they are indistinguishable but I'm not sure how I would write that.

Answer (score 1):

Since the balls are indistinguishable, the different final configurations are entirely determined by how many balls are in each urn from $1$ to $k$ (here $k=7$). So the outcomes, as you mentioned in the comments, can be identified with $k$-tuples $(m_1,\ldots, m_k)$, where $m_i$ is the number of balls in urn number $i$. Also, each ball has to go somewhere, so $m_1+\ldots+m_k= n$, where $n$ is the total number of balls.

So without any constraints, the total number of configurations is equal to the cardinality of the set $$S(n,k)=\{(m_1,\ldots, m_k):m_1+\ldots + m_k=n\}.$$ We note that $$|S(n,k)|=\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{n+k-1}{n}$$ such tuples. This is valid for $n=0,1,\ldots$ and $k=1,2,\ldots$. Note that the $m_i$ are allowed to be zero (because we aren't yet considering constraints such as "each urn must have at least one ball -- we'll get to that in a moment).

This is the "stars and bars" argument (I've hard people take issue with this name and propose better names, but "stars and bars" will get you to a wikipedia page).

Here's how we arrive at $\binom{n+k-1}{n}$. Imagine we have $n$ balls to be distributed into $k$ urns. Imagine we have $n+k-1$ spots. We choose $k-1$ of those spots to put down a "divider" (or a bar), and the rest of the spots get the stars. These $k-1$ dividers create $n$ groups of stars (some of those groups may have zero stars in them). To the left of the first divider is urn number $1$, then between the first and second divider is bin $2$, etc. There are exactly $\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ ways to choose which $k-1$ of the $n+k-1$ spots will get the bars.

Example: Let's take $n=2$ balls and $k=2$ bins. We'll take $2+2-1=3$ spots. There are $\binom{2+2-1}{2-1}=\binom{3}{1}=3$ ways to choose which $1$ of the three spots will be a bar. We get $$\begin{array}{lll} \bigr| & \star & \star \\ \star & \bigr| & \star \\ \star & \star & \bigr|\end{array}$$

The first line is $0$ balls in urn $1$ and $2$ in urn $2$. The next is $1$ in each. The last is $2$ in urn $1$ and $0$ in urn $2$.

Now what about the constraints? If we say each urn must have at least one ball, of course we need $n\geqslant k$ (at least as many balls as urns). Since the balls are indistinguishable, just take $k$ balls and put one in each urn. Then the question becomes how to distribute the remaining $n-k$ balls, and now there are no remaining constraints. Anything we do with the remaining $n-k$ balls will satisfy the "one ball in each urn" constraint. This is like stars and bars, except we have $n-k$ instead of $n$ balls, so the formula becomes $$\binom{(n-k)+k-1}{k-1}=\binom{n-1}{k-1},$$ which is exactly the formula you have for the denominator.

What about the constraint that each urn must have at least one ball and at least one has $15$. Let's go with your approach and calculate the situation in which one has exactly $x$ for $x=15,16,17,18,19$.

Let's look at $x=15$. First, pick one of the seven urns to get $15$ balls. There are $\binom{7}{1}=7$ ways to do this. Put fifteen balls in this urn. It doesn't matter which fifteen, so the only choice we've made so far is which of the seven urns. So now we have $10$ balls left to go in the six remaining urns, and each of the six remaining urns must get at least one ball. There are $\binom{10-1}{6-1}=\binom{9}{5}$ ways to do distribute the remaining balls among the other urns.

We want to make sure we haven't double counted anything. We know that after we've chosen the first urn, all of the $\binom{9}{5}$ ways to distribute the remaining balls are distinct. The only thing we need to check is that we couldn't possibly end up at the same configuration by choosing, say, urn $1$ first to get $15$ and then distributing the rest doesn't give the same final configuration as choosing, say, urn $2$ first to get the $15$ and distributing the remaining balls after that. But that's clearly true, since there can't be more than one urn with fifteen balls.

In order to understand the importance of the last step: If the question asked how many configurations had an urn with at least $5$ balls, we could pick urn $1$, put five balls in it, and then distribute the remaining balls in the remaining urns in such a way that urn $2$ also gets five balls (and, say, $2$ in each of the other urns). Or we could pick urn $2$, put five balls in it, and then distribute the remaining balls in the other bins in such a way that urn $1$ gets $5$ and then urns $3$ through $7$ get $2$ balls each. In this situation, the approach from the preceding paragraph would double count $(5,5,2,2,2,2,2)$.

Comment: Thank you. I see what I was doing now. Appreciate it.

Comment: @Haris Please read the question and my answer carefully.

Comment: OP's original question said their first attempt **was** to count the case in which one urn contains **exactly** fifteen, then repeat through nineteen. My answer also explicitly says that I am, in fact, counting the situation in which one urn has **exactly** fifteen, and that this approach would be repeated through nineteen.

Comment: From the question: 

"The probability that one has exactly $15$ is $\ldots$. I planned to do that for $16$, $17$, and $18$, then add them."

Comment: I am aware. OP's approach was $$\mathbb{P}(\text{One of the urns has at least }15\text{ balls})=\sum_{x=15}^{19}\mathbb{P}(\text{One of the urns has exactly }x\text{ balls}).$$ OP and I are both calculating the probability that one urn has at least $15$ balls by calculating the sum on the right side of this equation, and we both said as much. You, OP, and I are all working on exactly the same problem (one urn has at least $15$). It's just that OP did not calculate the other terms because their first summand was questionable, and I only did $x=15$ because it gives the full idea for other $x$

Comment: No worries! I spent an hour recently writing up an answer to a misread question.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternate approach**

One of the urns must have at least $15$ balls and the other six urns must have at least $1$ ball each. So let's start by placing $14$ balls in one of the urns. The number of ways to do that would be $7 \choose 1$. $^*$

Now we have $11$ balls remaining. They will go into any of the seven urns with the condition that each urn gets at least $1$ balls. So, $10 \choose 6$.

This would ensure that one urn has at least $14 + 1 = 15$ balls.

So the total number of ways $ = {7 \choose 1} \times {10 \choose 6}$

---

$^*$ No more than one urn can have $15$ or more balls at a time, so the cases are mutually exclusive and we don't need to worry about double counting.

Also, it's important to not that this solution works only when the question states that the balls are indistinguishable and that all configurations are equally likely.